# Why notification badge in Android O does not show when setGroupSummary is set?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

I was wondering and checked most of the questions here, and did some research on why this is happening, because how I set my badge is based on [Android Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification)

I encountered that my badge does not show when I have set the

`builder.setGroupSummary(true);` I also did a lot of debugging checking if I have done anything wrong within my code but whenever I remove this line of code, the badge shows up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a separate group notification and set the group summary flag true and it becomes the parent notification that bundles other notifications with the same group key within itself. Like this:

[setgroup() in notification not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058887/setgroup-in-notification-not-working)

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. What you provided may be a workaround but that does not answer it.

Comment: @EdwardBryan please share your code for further better understanding

Comment: The link you provided has a comment that leads to the correct documentation as to why setGroupSummary and setShowBadge does not work. It seems that setGroupSummary should be added on Group Notification and setShowBadge should be on the Child Notification